# Best way to rollout open telemetry helm operators and resources in a multi-cluster K8s Setup

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, grafana, kubernetes-helm

I am currently tasked with building an observability pipeline based on open telemetry. We are looking at shipping all 3 key signals (metrics, traces, and logs) to the Grafana cloud. We also have a compliance requirement to separate the logging data of different teams and their applications. While one such team have a cluster to itself and Grafana Cloud supports multi-tenancy by allowing the creation of multiple organisations and stacks, there are teams that share the same cluster. On Grafana Cloud, I am using stacks within the same org to separate the o11y backends of each team. How best can I go about this?

For context, we currently have a self-hosted within the K8s cluster based upon the Kube-Prometheus operator with Thanos enabled. I am looking at pushing data to the Prometheus, Loki and Tempo backends on Grafana Cloud. I feel that selectively filtering which namespaces of apps need to be scraped for metrics data may be quite involving and messy and deploying separate instances of the Otel Operator and Collector may be too resource-intensive. What do you recommend? Has anyone built an 011y pipeline for this kind of use case using the Otel collectors alone without having to use the Grafana agent alongside?
Thank you.